# Determining whether I should to upgrade an Apache web server (by server-status data)

Tags: apache, webmin, virtualmin

This is about an Apache web server. I'm wondering whether I should upgrade the current plan (3xCPU, 8GB). Or maybe there is a need of adjusting some settings like MaxClients. Not sure if there is a way to determine how many resources I need.

In webalizer stats there are a great deal of records with http response code "408 Request Timeout".

Here are my current Server-Status module results. Hopefully someone will be able to explain some important criteria if there are any at all.

```
Server uptime: 20 hours 36 minutes 39 seconds
Server load: 0.01 0.03 0.05
Total accesses: 2885489 - Total Traffic: 64.3 GB
CPU Usage: u338.4 s150.25 cu0 cs0 - .659% CPU load
38.9 requests/sec - 0.9 MB/second - 23.4 kB/request
177 requests currently being processed, 164 idle workers
._K.R......_..._._._K.RR......R.R_......._._K_...R...R.....___.C
..._KR.R...RC.R._.._...KW.......R.R........R...._...R._.R...__..
R_...R....R.......__R.....K_._............__.K...._R.....R.__._K
R......K....K.....K...._.R._.___._CRR...CRR._....W........__..C.
._....R..__.._..._....._.._....._..._._.KK..._R_..K........_.WR_
.R..._.K.....K..KR._.W.R........R__._.....C.._...._......K.KR.R.
K........K..._K.RR._R..RKR..._...R..._....C._....._....._.KR..._
._......._...R....KR........R.._..._.__.RK......R...K_...._.....
_..._....R..._...._........._._C.._R....._.R.R..C..._...R._.K...
R..._RKC..R..R..__...._..._.._......_.R..KC_...._......R._...__W
.C__...R.._R.K_._K......R.K...K..C_.K.K_..K..__R...RRR__......R.
..._K._K__....._.__....K_....W.....__.._._.....RR_R..K.__..KR...
R.._R_.C_.R....._..._....._......W._.K._..R_...K._..._...R.._...
..__CC..._....K.K......._R..K..K__R........K._......._RKK..__...
_.....R...R.......C_.K......W.R...._._.R.K._K...RK._.R_._._..._.
......._R._.RR.C_R.....R..._..._C...._.....R.__..C..R.........R.
Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```